# (C#) Instantiated Under Conditions, Else Reuse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm extremely new to programming so bear with me.

```
public void clickWood()
{
   //Check If The Player Has Gotten Wood Previously
   if(_hasWood == false)
    {

        GameObject newItem = Instantiate(wood_prefab) as GameObject;

        //Initial Displayed Name
        newItem.GetComponent<ButtonSetter>().setName("WOOD: ");

        //Starts with 0 Wood, set to 1
        newItem.GetComponent<ButtonSetter>().item_count += 1;

        newItem.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Content").transform,false);

        //Got their first wood, should run else from now on
        _hasWood = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //SEE CONTINUED POST
    }
}
```

So, within the else statement, I want to basically say,

They got their first wood, so we created a panel to display information about the wood they have. Now I want to say, since we have already instantiated the displayPanel, we just want to work from that and adjust the object's variable that controls the integer part of "Wood: 0"

This should be

```
newItem.GetComponent<ButtonSetter>().item_count
```

But if I try accessing that within the else statement as shown:

```
newItem.GetComponent<ButtonSetter>().item_count += 1;
```

It tells me that newItem does not exist within the current context.
How can I Instantiate something under certain conditions, then after the condition was met, take the instantiated object and work with its script/variables?

[Visual representation of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbVqz.png)

Comment: Store `newItem` onto a field of your object, just like you have `_hasWood` as a field.

Comment: To elaborate more on @ChrisSinclair point, your  `GameObject newItem = Instantiate(wood_prefab) as GameObject; ` is with in the scope of if block. So why don't you place you newItem GameObject reference before if block and keep the object instantiation with in the if block. `GameObject newItem = null` and `newItem = Instantiate(wood_prefab) as GameObject;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to restructure your code a little bit.

So here's how I would do it

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour {
    public string itemName;
    public int count;
}
```

I will create a base class `Item` for wood, iron or whatever is there in your game.

Next, I will Create a Handler Script, that keeps track of all Items that are clicked/not Clicked

### Handler.cs

public class Handler : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Item itemPrefab;

public Dictionary<string, Item> displayItems= new Dictionary<string, Item>();

public void OnWoodClicked()
{
    OnItemClicked("wood");
}

public void OnIronClicked()
{
    OnItemClicked("iron");
}

private void OnItemClicked(string itemKey)
{
    if (displayItems.ContainsKey(itemKey))
    {
        displayItems[itemKey].count++;
    }
    else
    {
        Item item = Instantiate(itemPrefab);
        item.count = 1;
        item.itemName=itemKey;
        displayItems.Add(itemKey, item);

    }
}
}
```

So To keep track of created items, I have created a dictionary public `Dictionary<string, Item> displayItems;`

In this script `OnItemClicked(string itemKey)` Method will check If Item of this type is already created or not. (By checking if that key exists)

If that item is not created then we will Instantiate new `Item` (Prefab of display Item you want to show) and add that to the dictionary according to its key.

But if it already exists, then simply access that object as `displayItems[itemKey]` as you like

So for example, if you click on Wood, you will get access to wood display item as `displayItems["wood"]`.

I hope this helps.
Just place a comment if you want me to make it clearer.

Comment: There we go! As a newbie - seeing the messy system I am trying to achieve be put into simpler and cleaner code helps a lot! Will give this a go, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I am glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

As it's currently written, newItem only lives in the "IF" clause of the code, so the "ELSE" clause can't see it.

If you assign it to a class-level field (like it appears you have _hasWood assigned at the class level) then you will be able to access it in either the "IF" or "ELSE" blocks, and maintain the count for the life of the object "clickWood()" is called from.

```
private bool _hasWood;
private GameObject _woodItem;

public void clickWood()
{
    //Check If The Player Has Gotten Wood Previously
    if(_hasWood == false)
    {

        _woodItem= Instantiate(wood_prefab) as GameObject;

        //Initial Displayed Name
        _woodItem.GetComponent<ButtonSetter>().setName("WOOD: ");

        //Starts with 0 Wood, set to 1
        _woodItem.GetComponent<ButtonSetter>().item_count += 1;

        _woodItem.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Content").transform,false);

        //Got their first wood, should run else from now on
        _hasWood = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _woodItem.GetComponent<ButtonSetter>().item_count += 1;
    }
}
```